# Scrollview navigation error

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uiscrollview

When im trying to put navigation and tool bar in scrollbar xib ,both are moving while am moving the scroll view up and down?How can i make the navigatiobar and toolbar view constant and scrollview movable?Please help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding navigation and tool bar on the scrollview, thats why they are moving the scrolling the scrollview . Add navigation and tool bar on the view not on scrollview

Answer (score 0):

1. Put a UIView on the xib file
2. Put UINavigationBar on top of the UIView
3. Put UIToolBar on bottom of thw UIView
4. Put UIScrollView on UIView in middle of the top navigation bar and bottom tool bar.

Please note the UIScrollView start exactly after the navigation bar and should end exactly before the tool bar.